# Parenthesis works in bash shell itself, but not in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I can run this command from my command line prompt:

```
cp -r folder/!(exclude-me) ./
```

To recursively copy all contents of `folder` *except* for the subdirectory named `exclude-me` into the current directory.  This works exactly as intended.  However, I need this to work in a bash script I've written, where I have this:

```
if [ -d "folder" ]; then
  cp -r folder/!(exclude-me) ./
  rm -rf folder
fi
```

But when I run the script:

```
bash my-script.sh
```

I get this:

```
my-script.sh: line 30: syntax error near unexpected token `('
my-script.sh: line 30: `  cp -r folder/!(exclude-me) ./'
```

And I'm at a loss as to why it works from the command prompt, but the exact same line doesn't work in a bash script.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's because the syntax you're using depends on a particular bash feature which is not activated.  You can activate it by adding the relevant command to your script:

```
## Enable extended globbing features
shopt -s extglob

if [ -d "folder" ]; then
  cp -r folder/!(exclude-me) ./ &&
    rm -rf folder
fi
```

This is the relevant section of `man bash`:

> ```
>   If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
>   extended  pattern  matching operators are recognized.  In the following
>   description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
>   by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the fol‐
>   lowing sub-patterns:
>
>          ?(pattern-list)
>                 Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>          *(pattern-list)
>                 Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>          +(pattern-list)
>                 Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>          @(pattern-list)
>                 Matches one of the given patterns
>          !(pattern-list)
>                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

The reason it is enabled in interactive invocations of bash in your case may be because you have `shopt -s extglob` in your `~/.bashrc` or because you're using https://github.com/scop/bash-completion (as found in the `bash-completion` package in Debian-based OSes at least) included via `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` which [does enable `extglob` upon initialisation](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/b12639a6becec13a0a2c06173ba40fb3bbe972e1/bash_completion#L45).

Note that those ksh-style extended glob operators can also be disabled altogether at build time by passing `--disable-extended-glob` to the `configure` script in the bash source code, or be enabled by default with `--enable-extended-glob-default`.

However note that `extglob` breaks POSIX compliance. For instance, while the behaviour for `echo !(x)` is unspecified in the POSIX `sh` language,

```
a='!(x)'
echo $a
```

Is required to output `!(x)` assuming the default value of `$IFS`, not the list of filenames in the current directory other than `x`, so that shouldn't be done for builds of `bash` that are intended to be used as `sh`. In ksh, those `X(...)` operators are enabled by default but not recognised upon expansions.

Comment: This is the second time I find this answer (yes, bad memory). This time tried to put run `env > file1` in the script and execute `./it`, and then `env > file2` and `source it`, in the hope that I'd have found a difference in the `env`s, which is not the case. How can I programmatically list all the difference between two shells (in this case interactive vs non-interactive)?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis see [Differentiate Interactive login and non-interactive non-login shell](//askubuntu.com/a/879400) and [How to check if a shell is login/interactive/batch](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/26676).

Answer (score 3):

Add this line near top of your script:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

`!(...)` is an extended pattern matching feature, you need `extglob` option enable to use it. See [shopt builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) for more details.

Comment: The "near top of your script" requirement just bit me. Trying to do `shopt -s extglob` within an "if" statement in a script doesn't seem to work, you still get the error. But placing the `shopt -s` immediately after the header line did work.