# !(*.sh) works on the command line but not in a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, wildcards

When I use the code below in a terminal on Ubuntu, it works fine:

```
rm !(*.sh) -rf
```

But if I place the same line code in a shell script (`clean.sh`) and run shell script from terminal, it throws error as this

clean.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm !(*.sh) -rf
```

Error I get:

```
./clean.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./clean.sh: line 2: `rm !(*.sh) -rf'
```

can you help?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/656425/80864

Comment: Could you please tell us what that rm command does? Just curious to know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parenthesis works in bash shell itself, but not in bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157541/parenthesis-works-in-bash-shell-itself-but-not-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Shell Script Approach

By default, globs don't work in a BASH script (although you can turn them on with `shopt`). If the shell script ever gets run by a non-BASH interpreter, globs might not work at all.

You can get the same effect using the `find` command, which is how I'd recommend doing it (because of how much more control you can have once your requirements grow).

Try this on for size:
`find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -iname "*.sh" -exec rm -rf {} \;`

#### Makefile Approach

Another approach you could take:

If you're doing something that wants to be cleaned afterwards, there's a good chance that a Makefile is the right tool for the job, rather than a bunch of clean.sh, build.sh, install.sh, etc.

This is especially true if you want to make sure your recipes always happen in order, or if you don't always want to re-run the recipes that produce an output.

A simple Makefile that did the same thing would look like this:
(note that the whitespace before `rm` needs to be a tab because that's how make rolls)

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.sh)
CLEAN_FILES := $(filter-out $(SOURCES),$(wildcard *))
CLEAN_FILES := $(filter-out Makefile,$(CLEAN_FILES))

build: $(SOURCES)
    YOUR_RECIPE_HERE

clean:
    rm -rf $(CLEAN_FILES)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to turn `extglob` on:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash, certain [patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) are not enabled by default, but can be turned on by setting an option with [`shopt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin). The patterns `!(NOT-THIS)`, `@(THIS|THAT)`, `*(ZERO-OR-MORE)`, `+(ONE-OR-MORE)` and `?(OPTIONAL)`, which didn't exist in early Unix shells, were later added in ksh, and aren't standardized by POSIX, are not recognized by default, you have to run `shopt -s extglob` first.

You can use these patterns on the command line; this indicates that you have `shopt -s extglob` in your `.bashrc`. That file is only read by interactive shells, not by scripts.

(If the environment variable `BASH_ENV` is set when bash starts running a script, then bash reads the file it designates, but I don't recommend relying on that, because it would make your script work only when `BASH_ENV` is set to the value that you expect, and only if you don't change the file it points to.)

Just include `shopt -s extglob` at the top of your script, below the `#!/bin/bash` line.