# mv throw error when executed in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, mv

OS: Ubuntu

I have the folder testfolder/subfolder with content
backup
file1.txt
file2.txt
testFolder

And I have script testfolder/testMv.sh

Now I'm inside of the bash session and do the following:

```
echo "$SHELL"
cd testfolder/subfolder
echo "bla" > file1.txt
echo "bla" > file2.txt
mkdir trs
ls
mv "!(backup)" backup
```

output

```
/bin/bash
backup  file1.txt  file2.txt  trs
```

Work perfectly, all files and folder except backup moved, no error. Live is great.

Now put all the same to the testfolder/testMv.sh

```
echo "bla" > file1.txt
echo "bla" > file2.txt
mkdir trs
ls
echo mv "!(backup)" backup
mv "!(backup)" backup
```

In the same bash, on the same machine doing:

```
cd testfolder/subfolder
../testMv.sh
```

Output:

```
backup  file1.txt  file2.txt  trs
mv !(backup) backup
mv: cannot stat '!(backup)': No such file or directory
```

Why???

PS I know how to avoid usage of mv, I just want to understand why the sh script works in different way from the shell itself.

Comment: You may need to enable the shell's `extglob` option - see [Parenthesis works in bash shell itself, but not in bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157541/parenthesis-works-in-bash-shell-itself-but-not-in-bash-script). You script also lacks a shebang.

Comment: What do you expect `"!(backup)"` to do? In bash's interactive mode it'll be treated as a history reference (unless `extglob` is enabled). Scripts normally run in non-interactive mode, so history is disabled. Note that it won't work as an extended glob expression (either interactively or in a script), because it's in double-quotes.

Comment: Are you sure you used double quotes around `!(backup)` when you successfully used `mv` interactively? The quotes would have _disabled_ the globbing, even if `extglob` was enabled.

Comment: @GordonDavisson "!()" means "exclude", !() mean history.

@

Comment: @steeldriver this is the bingo, thanks. Strange that I'vnt found this post during hours of searching.

Comment: @FreemanRU Glob expressions (extended or otherwise) don't get expanded when they're in double-quotes, so `"!()"` will either be treated as a history expansion (if `extglob` is off) or just a plain string (if `extglob` is on, or it's not bash). Unless you've redefined `mv` to make it run its arguments through another level of glob expansion (which is something I'd recommend strongly against).